# gradle copy task to custom location

Tags: gradle

let's assume
libsDir = /src/nbwebservice/test1/libs and /src/nbwebservice/test2/libs

I want to copy jars from those directories to 
location = /jars/test1 and /jars/test2 (custom location just differentiated by project name.

task copyJarsWithDependency(type: copy){
from configurations.testRuntime
into location
}

I am not able to find relevance online on how to do it?

Comment: google for "gradle copy task" and read this: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html

Comment: That is the first thing which anybody does google but thanks for pointing out. check out the answer. i wanted to preserve the project names where jar files are being copied from so was not able to find exact name but for others it is $archiveBaseName.

Comment: @AnkitKumar, so next time please be more precise about the problem. Also please edit the question and format it appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

location = /jars/$archivesBaseName

$archivesBaseName keeps track of the project name